# What Exchange Throttling Policy was tripped?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, throttling, ews-managed-api

I have a .net app that does a lot of EWS work against an on-prem instance of exchange 2016 using the [ews-managed-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api) with impersonation.   A couple mailboxes fail to load all their items using the FindItems method.   I get a ServerBusyException with ErrorCode=ErrorServerBusy and BackOffMilliseconds=2998781(or similar ms).

On the exchange server, I see this corresponding error:

> Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.OverBudgetException:
>   This operation exceeds the throttling budget for policy part
>   'LocalTime'  policy value '0'   Budget type: 'Ews'.  Suggested backoff
>   time 299781 ms.

Here are the relevant policy settings that apply to my impersonation account:

```
Get-ThrottlingPolicy MyServiceThrottlingPolicy | fl *EWS*

EwsCostThreshold                      : Unlimited
EwsMaxConcurrency                     : 6000
EwsMaxBurst                           : Unlimited
EwsRechargeRate                       : Unlimited
EwsCutoffBalance                      : Unlimited
EwsMaxSubscriptions                   : 5000
```

What policy do I need to tweak to adjust my throttling policy to allow my traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know to know this is to check theEWS Log on the CAS server that is processing the requests. The default log location is

C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Vxx\Logging\Ews

There some more information on the log configuration options in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/karywa/2016/07/15/exchange-server-20132016-ews-logging-configuration/

Most likely if you reduce the number of properties your finditems request is asking for that will help reduce throttling.

Comment: The OverBudgetException came from EWS logs.  Pasted the most relevant message - which is a little to obscure to help here.  Just trying to see what 'LocalTime' policy part applies to so I can adjust the applicable policy. 

I am already at a bare bones propertyset.

Comment: I'd suggest you look more at the log, what you have posted is generally the end of the chain but you should be seeing the budget usage before you get a back-off. Also if your using impersonation then the charge is against the Mailbox your accessing throttle policy not the security context your using so what you have show in Get-ThrottlingPolicy is not relevant when your impersonating. I would be if you where just accessing the Mailbox using delegation

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the other throttling policy.  I ended up creating a new policy with Unlimited EwsRechargeRate to assign large mailboxes to.